# capturing yum update transaction to replicate on another machine

Tags: rhel, yum, amazon-linux

Looking for a way to capture a "yum update" on machine "A" and replicate the exact same actions on machine "B" (maybe at a later date after testing on machine "A").  We want to be able to patch dev, let the updates "bake in" for some length of time, then promote those same updates to production.  I assume this is potentially possible by doing something like:

```
rpm -qa > installed-software.log
yum install $(cat installed-software.log)
```

But that doesn't feel very efficient.

Comment: Hi @JeffSchaller, thanks for the feedback - this is my first post.  Don't want to get too off topic, but if you could provide a title edit that would be more appropriate it might help me understand the critique.  The way I read it, the title is already a summary with the body going into more detail to explain specifics.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Dan, and welcome to the site! I was mainly reacting to the first sentence, which you've edited out. I've written a [Meta post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5015/117549) where I put some ideas together. Beyond that, my only other suggestion would be to call out version numbers in the title and/or body -- is it important to you that the prod systems end up with the exact same *versions* of packages that dev did, or just that the same *set* of packages were updated to some level? Also: do you have Satellite or local repos set up -- or do the machines go straight to RedHat?

Comment: [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/609541/edit) to add any clarifications, just as you've done already. Thank you!

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/608944/117549

Comment: Thanks @JeffSchaller, I'll review the meta post :)

Comment: The machines in questions are AWS EC2 instances with a mixture of rhel7 and amazon linux 2 (where machine "A" and machine "B" are always the same flavor).  RHEL7 would be pointed at Red Hat Update Infrastructure (RHUI) provided by AWS and AMZN Linux 2 would be pointed at their repos.  No satellite involved unfortunately as I believe it has built in functionality similar to what I'm looking for.  

I would be looking for the packages to be update to the same exact version.

Comment: These would be great [edits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/609541/edit) to the question ... :)

Comment: As a word of caution: if your machines ever diverge (I know this "never happens" to me, because I've never unexpectedly needed `tcpdump` or whatever), just applying the same updates won't make them converge again. That being said: if you answer "no" to `yum`'s confirmation prompt, it tells you that if you change your mind, the transaction is stored in a `.txsave` (??, going off memory) file. I've never investigated the format of this file, it might be portable between already-identical machines.